# What do we mean "exactly" by effective capacitance?

Tags: electric-circuits, terminology, capacitance

For series combination, effective resistance means replace all the resistors by a single resistor in which current flowing is the same.
For parallel, it means replace all the resistors by a single resistor in which potential difference across it is same.
But what does it mean in case of effective capacitance?

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor is described by the equation

$$Q = CV$$

or

$$I = C\frac{dV}{dt}.$$

The equivalent capacitance of a network of capacitors, with two nodes chosen to form a "port" into which the equivalent capacitance is to be measured, is the value $C_{eq}$ such that

$$I_p = C_{eq}\frac{dV_p}{dt},$$

where $I_p$ is the current in to the port and $V_p$ is the voltage across the port.

In qualitative terms, it's the value of a single capacitor that can be substituted for the whole network, which would behave the same as that network as far as signals applied to the port are concerned.